# View don't refresh Button - Java FX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8

This is my first project in JAVAFX , it's a simple program for the moment. My problem is that when the program starts the button "loadLogButton" of the FXMLLoadLogController charge the properly message. But when I choose another language in the comboBox , the setter of the button works fine but the view is not refreshed. What's the problem?

RPV: The function chargeI18nValues of the LoadLogController works fine but the button text is not refreshed in the program when its called from the SolverManager.

Codes:

SolverAssistant.java

```
public class SolverAssistant extends Application {

    public static ResourceBundle messages;
    public static Utils utils = new Utils();
    public static SolverManager manager;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Load the resource bundle
        this.chargeResourceBundleLanguage();

        // Load Controllers
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());
        manager = new SolverManager(scene);
        manager.showMainView();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void chargeResourceBundleLanguage() {
        String defaultLanguage = utils.fileReader(new File("lang.txt"));
        switch (defaultLanguage) {
            case "en":
                messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
                break;
            case "es":
                messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("es"));
                break;
            case "cat":
                messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("cat"));
                break;
            default:
                messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

SolverManager.java

```
public class SolverManager {

    private final Scene scene;
    private FXMLMainController mainController;
    private FXMLLoadLogController logController;

    public SolverManager(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void showMainView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader mainLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml"));
        scene.setRoot((Parent) mainLoader.load());
        mainController = mainLoader.<FXMLMainController>getController();
        FXMLLoader loadLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLLoadLog.fxml"));
        loadLoader.load();
        logController = loadLoader.<FXMLLoadLogController>getController();
    }

    public void refreshI18nResources() {
        mainController.chargeI18nValues();
        logController.chargeI18nValues();
    }
}
```

FXMLMainController.java

```
public class FXMLMainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboLanguage;

    @FXML
    private Tab loadTab;

    @FXML
    private Tab editTab;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.chargeI18nValues();
        this.chargeLanguageComboBox(SolverAssistant.messages.getLocale());
        comboLanguage.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(this.languageComboBoxListener());
    }

    public void chargeI18nValues() {
        loadTab.setText(SolverAssistant.messages.getString("LoadLog"));
        editTab.setText(SolverAssistant.messages.getString("EditLog"));
    }

    private void chargeLanguageComboBox(Locale language) {
        comboLanguage.getItems().addAll(
                "Català",
                "English",
                "Español"
        );
        switch (language.getLanguage()) {
            case "cat":
                comboLanguage.setValue("Català");
                break;
            case "es":
                comboLanguage.setValue("Español");
                break;
            case "en":
                comboLanguage.setValue("English");
                break;
        }
    }

    // -------- Listeners
    private ChangeListener languageComboBoxListener() {
        return new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            }

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                switch ((String) newValue) {
                    case "Català":
                        SolverAssistant.messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("cat"));
                        SolverAssistant.utils.fileWriter("lang.txt", "cat");
                        break;
                    case "Español":
                        SolverAssistant.messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("es"));
                        SolverAssistant.utils.fileWriter("lang.txt", "es");
                        break;
                    case "English":
                        SolverAssistant.messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.bundle", Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
                        SolverAssistant.utils.fileWriter("lang.txt", "en");
                        break;
                }
                SolverAssistant.manager.refreshI18nResources();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

FXMLLoadLogController.java

```
public class FXMLLoadLogController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label logNameLabel;

    @FXML
    private TextArea logTextArea;

    @FXML
    private Button loadLogButton;

    //private String logName;
    private final String logName = "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\ahmaxsat-ls-ms_crafted-COMPLETE-1800-3500-2.log";
    private String log;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.chargeI18nValues();
    }

    public void chargeI18nValues() {
        loadLogButton.setText(SolverAssistant.messages.getString("OpenNewLog"));
    }

    // -------- Actions
    @FXML
    private void openLog(ActionEvent event) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle(SolverAssistant.messages.getString("Open"));
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        // Selecting File
        //if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        if (true) {
            //File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            log = SolverAssistant.utils.fileReader(new File(logName));
            logNameLabel.setText(logName);
            logTextArea.setText(log);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `SolverAssistant.messages.getString(...)` in `chargeI18nValues()` methods returns the right string with right language on combobox item change.

Comment: Yes it's right , if I put a System.out.println(loadLogButton.getText()); in the chargeI18nValues function of the LoadLogController after the set,  show me that the button change the text fine but it's not showed on the view. It's like the view is not refreshed...

Comment: Which version of API and OS? Try to create new demo project where you will set the text of label to arbitrary value on button click. By doing this it will be determined if the prbolem environment specific or your code specific.

Comment: It works fine a simple code in a new project , the key is that the main view is refreshed , I mean , the text on tabs is properly changed and showed , but the content of the tabs is changed but not refreshed after the first change.

Maybe the problem is how I linked the content of the tabs (AnchorPanel) because after the initialize I can change them , but it's not showed.

I work on W8 and here is the github maybe it's easy too see the problem: https://github.com/danielcasanovas/SolverAssistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are 2 instances of sub/child FXMLs (and their controllers). These are:
1) Loaded from `SolverManager.showMainView()` using `FXMLLoader`
2) Loaded from **FXMLMain.fxml** via `<fx:include>`s

The scene contains the ones loaded via includes, but text changes happen at the other ones. To fix the problem you need you choose one of these approaches, either remove includes or remove fxmlloadings. Here is the second approach:

```
public class SolverManager {

    private final Scene scene;
    private FXMLMainController mainController;
//    private FXMLLoadLogController loadLogController;
//    private FXMLEditLogController editLogController;

    public SolverManager(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void showMainView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader mainLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml"));
        scene.setRoot((Parent) mainLoader.load());
        mainController = mainLoader.<FXMLMainController>getController();

//        FXMLLoader loadLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLLoadLog.fxml"));
//        loadLoader.load();
//        loadLogController = loadLoader.<FXMLLoadLogController>getController();
//        FXMLLoader editLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLEditLog.fxml"));
//        editLoader.load();
//        editLogController = editLoader.<FXMLEditLogController>getController();
    }

    public void refreshI18nResources() {
        mainController.chargeI18nValues();
//        loadLogController.chargeI18nValues();
//        editLogController.chargeI18nValues();
    }
}
```

Add following lines to `FXMLMainController`:

```
@FXML
private FXMLLoadLogController barTabPageLoadController;

@FXML
private FXMLEditLogController barTabPageEditController;
```

(The variable name come from `fx:id` + ***Controller***. See [Subcontroller not being injected into main controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790785/subcontroller-not-being-injected-into-main-controller))

and change the following in the same file

```
public void chargeI18nValues() {
    loadTab.setText(SolverAssistant.messages.getString("LoadLog"));
    editTab.setText(SolverAssistant.messages.getString("EditLog"));
    barTabPageLoadController.chargeI18nValues();
    barTabPageEditController.chargeI18nValues();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense , it's my first project and I don't have the concepts clear yet, this afternoon I will try it but seems really good solution, thank you so much for your help!