# Null exception when I try to access a controller that I passed using JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a root layout with multiples Tabs. From my main App I open the root layout. There I included multiple FXMLs with their own controllers.
I am trying to pass the main controller to one of the Tabes controller.

The issue I am having, everything works as expected, but I get a `null` exception when I try to click on an action button from the new tab.

#### RootLayout FXML

```
<fx:indlue fx:id="myNewTabAnchorPane" source="NewTabFXML.fxml"/>
```

#### RootLayout Controller

```
@FXML NewTabController newTabController;

mainTabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>(){
    @override
    public void change(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldValue, Tab newValue){
        if(newValue == myTab){
        newTabController.setMyRootController(this);
    }
```

#### NewTabController

```
public void setMyRootController(RootController rootController){
this.rootController = rootController;
System.out.println(rootController.getID); // this prints fine
}
```

However, if I trigger this action I get blank from the same controller

```
@FXML 
public void createAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
System.out.println(rootController.getID); // with this I get null value. 
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it `ntc` or `ect`? Assuming both should be `nct` you do not keep a reference to the controller and you do not use it with `FXMLLoader` which means you're likely using 2 different controller instances: one with the `FXMLLoader` and another one for setting the root controller. This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Comment: The only difference is that I have multiple tabs that use different Fxmls that they use their own controllers. So I am not showing a new stage as it's already open. How can I achieve that with my setup?

Comment: I didn't write anything about stages. If you're refering to the question I linked: It doesn't matter if the content you load is shown in a new stage or not, the approach to passing the information to the controller is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
 @FXML NewTabController newTabController;
```

It should be `myNewTabAnchorPaneController` which is not a partially lowercased class name, but `fx:id + Controller` concatenation.

Comment: Thanks so much Sergey! I truly appreciate you help here. I not sure if this is documented someone where, I hope it is. Thanks again!